# How to block a specific user from your app?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an app that allows users to only log in through Facebook. The backend is Parse. I have many fake users creating accounts and screwing up my app, posting inappropriate things. Is there a way to block a list of Facebook accounts from logging in/using my app? I have the list of their Facebook IDs, but I am not sure how to block them by writing a Cloud Code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can´t you check the callback when the user tries to login and add a blacklist in your app? If they try to login you´ll just block their view.

Comment: but that means updating the app every time i need to add someone to this list. otherwise, every time the user logs in, i do an additional call to another server that has this blacklist and then block the user if needed. But is the additional call really necessary?

Comment: specially since, i have to block a user after they have logged in and screwed things up. So, I have to check if they are a bad user every time they open the app. Seems like a waste to me.

Comment: Just have that list in a database you can access and add/remove posts whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new boolean column to your `User` table to indicate if this user is blocked/blacklisted. Every time a Facebook user gets a new session, their `authData` field needs to be updated. So you can use the`beforeSave` trigger on Cloud to check if a user is blacklisted and return an error which prevents them from getting a new token and logging in at all.

Now to block a user, find their session record in the `Session` table and delete it which invalidates their token and logs them out. Then simply set their `blocked` field to `true`. They should not be able to log in to your app any more.